# Reading a text file using the BufferedReader class in Java

Tags: java, substring, bufferedreader

I am trying to create a static method called `findOccurrences()` which takes a single `String` argument called `subString`. Firstly, the method has to prompt the user for the pathname of a file with a `.txt` extension which is then used to create a `File` object. The method then needs to open a stream on that file. Subsequently, the method has to read from the stream a line at a time, and for each line, the method needs to print to the standard output the number of occurences of the string argument `subString` in that line.

An example output from the method should look like this:

```
The substring "FRED" occurs 2 times in line 1
The substring "FRED" occurs 1 times in line 2
The substring "FRED" occurs 4 times in line 3
The substring "FRED" occurs 0 times in line 4
```

The method needs to ensure that when the `while` loop has terminated, all the lines in the file have been read. The string holding the current line of the file should be converted to upper case. Within another loop, the method needs to determine the number of times its argument (converted to upper case) occurs as a substring in the current line. So, for example, if the current line holds the string "BRITAIN POSSESSES TALENT" searching for the substring "SSES" should produce two occurrences.

Now, I gave it my best shot and developed the code below for the required method. But unfortunately, each time I compile it, the compiler throws an error: `foreach not applicable to expression type` and that's where I get stuck! So I was just wondering if you guys can help out spot where I am going wrong please.

Below is the entire code that I have developed:

```
public static void countOccurrences (String subString)
{
   OUDialog.alert("Please choose a file to search");
   String pathname = OUFileChooser.getFilename();
   File aFile = new File(pathname);
   BufferedReader bufferedFileReader = null;

   int numOfOccurrencesInLine;
   int lineNumber = 0;
   int lineIndex;
   subString = subString.toUpperCase();
   String currentLine;
   try
   {
      bufferedFileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(aFile));
      currentLine = bufferedFileReader.readLine();
      while (currentLine != null)
      {
         currentLine = bufferedFileReader.readLine();
         currentLine.toUpperCase();
         lineIndex = currentLine.indexOf(subString, lineNumber);
         subString = currentLine.substring(lineIndex);
         numOfOccurrencesInLine = 0;
         for (int eachOccurrence : currentLine)
         {
            numOfOccurrencesInLine = numOfOccurrencesInLine + eachOccurrence;
            System.out.println("The substring " + subString + "occurs 2 times in line " + lineNumber);
         }
      }
   }
   catch (Exception anException)
   {
      System.out.println("Error: " + anException);
   }
   finally
   {
      try
      {
         bufferedFileReader.close();
      }
      catch (Exception anException)
      {
         System.out.println("Error: " + anException);
      }
   }
}
```

Thank you guys.

Comment: Personally, I think that's far too much functionality for a single method. But currentLine is a string; what are you really trying to do at that point?

Comment: currentLine is a string not an iterable of int

Comment: Read the last section of http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html. The way you read lines is also wrong. And read the javadoc of String.indexOf(): passing the line number as argument doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thank you guys, I appreciate your comments, I'll keep working on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the fact that you really should split up those functionalities into single methodes, you're using `foreach` wrong. You're iterating through an `String[]` array, so you need to change ´int eachOccurrence´ to `String eachOccurrence`.
Edit: You aren't actually iterating through an array. You want to iterate through a `String`, but `String` doesnt implement `Iterable`.
You should really grab a decent programming book. After carefully reading your code again, there are several mistakes. E.g. you read your line twice, overwriting the fist read line. Therefore just leave the 2nd `currentLine = bufferedFileReader.readLine();` (the one after the `null`check).